# Python: How do I compare all items in one list as a string to all items in another list?

Tags: python-3.x

```
for each_word1 in list_a:
    ###compare all values to...###
    for each_word2 in list_b:
        if each_word2 in list_b == any_word in list_a:
            add each_word2 to list_c
            ###something like that###
```

Comment: also i have no idea how to format yet on here... just got on here yesterday.. apologies but im working on it :)

Comment: please see my edit and correct anything I've misindented

Comment: nope youre good thats exactly what i was going for.. i know theres a tutorial somewhere lol thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python does have the figure of `set`s which are ideal for situation  like this. These are data structures that excel in fast comparison of containment, and has the same primitive operations we have in basic Math back in the first school grades.

Just convert one of your lists to a set (this will remove duplcates if any), and use the intersection operation. Convert the result back to a list if you need:

```
list_c = list(set(list_a).intersection(list_b))
```

Comment: Hmm I see what you mean and that makes sense. My fault for not explaining more. In this case I actually want all instances of the word. Also I will probably have to evaluate in an embedded loop unless there is a better way. Both lists are in files and in order to evaluate them I'm currently looping through each and them maybe compare each string in list to string in other list. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm going to loop up documentation for the intersection method though :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do (if I understand you correctly).

```
list_a = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
list_b = ['ghi', 'jkl', 'mno']
list_c = []

for string in list_a:
    if string in list_b:
        list_c.append(string)
```

Comment: yes that works great! its a little more confusing than that because each string is coming from a word file and I have to loop through each list but i think that will work great!